# Whata are the differences between Ethereum and Ethereum Classic?

Tags: security, ethereum-classic

What are the key differences between Ethereum and Ethereum Classic and what implications do they have for the future of the Ethereum network?

Answer (score 0):

there are several key differences between the two platforms:

Origin: Ethereum was created in 2015 as a result of a hard fork from the original Ethereum blockchain, following the DAO hack. Ethereum Classic, on the other hand, continued on the original blockchain and refused the hard fork.

Purpose: Ethereum's purpose is to be a decentralized platform for the creation of applications and smart contracts, while Ethereum Classic aims to preserve the original vision of Ethereum as a decentralized platform that is resistant to censorship and interference.

Consensus Algorithm: Ethereum has switched from a proof-of-work (PoW) to a proof-of-stake (PoS) consensus algorithm, while Ethereum Classic continues to use PoW.

Development Team: Ethereum has a large and active development community, while Ethereum Classic has a smaller, but dedicated team.

Token: The native token of Ethereum is called Ether (ETH), while the native token of Ethereum Classic is called Classic Ether (ETC).

Adoption: Ethereum has a larger user base and is more widely adopted, while Ethereum Classic has a smaller but dedicated community.

Upgradeability: Ethereum has a flexible architecture that allows for frequent updates and upgrades, while Ethereum Classic aims to maintain a more stable and unchanging codebase.